# how to answer the question using type 1 nested query?

Tags: sql, nested

Based on the tables below:

**You are required to list products with order quantities greater than 100 using Type 1 Nested query.**

[enter image description here][1]

```
PRODUCT(**PROD_ID**,PROD_NAME,SUPPLIER_ID,UNITPRICE,PACKAGE,ISDISCONTINUED)

ORDER ITEM(ID,ORDERID,PRODUCTID,UNITPRICE,QUANTITY)

USING THIS FORMULA:
    SELECT column-names
    FROM table-name1
    WHERE value IN (SELECT column-name
    FROM table-name2 
    WHERE condition)
```

Comment: What is a "type 1 nested query" for those of us who do not know?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you expecting,

```
select prod_name from product where productid in
(select prod_id from item where quantity > 100);
```